# Python append object elements to list in for loop, get duplicate element?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to Python. I want to add object to list in for loop. But I'm getting duplicate elements. Here is the code.

```
import pymysql
import dbUtil

db = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'nzdlfc')

cursor = db.cursor()


class Video:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = ''
        self.time = ''
        self.category = ''
        self.url = ''
        self.id = ''


def getVideoInfo():

    ls = dbUtil.get_data_tuple_ls("SELECT * FROM VIDEO")
    video_ls = []
    for i in ls:
        video_obj = Video
        video_obj.id = i[0]
        video_obj.title = i[1]
        video_obj.time = i[2]
        video_obj.category = i[4]
        video_obj.url = i[7]
        video_ls.append(video_obj)

    return video_ls


videoObj_ls = getVideoInfo()

for j in videoObj_ls:
    print(j.id)
    print(j.title)
    print(j.time)
    print(j.category)
    print(j.url)
```

I got 4 elements in DB, but when I print videoObj_ls, I got 4 the fourth elements. Anyone can guide me to fix this. Thanks very much.

Comment: You're not instantiating your video. It should be `video_obj = Video()` with parentheses. Otherwise you're just referencing the video class itself each time.

Comment: Thank you so much @khelwood, problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got the solution in khelwood's comment - as a more general answer, callables (classes, functions, methods etc) are not called if you don't explicitely apply the call operator, IOW the parens.

As a side note: you would certainly benefit from passing all values directly to you `Video` class initializer, and restricting your SQL query to the fields you actually use:

```
class Video:
    def __init__(self, id, title, time, category, url):
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.time = time
        self.category = category
        self.url = url


def getVideoInfo():
    # I assume the db fields have the same names as 
    # the class attributes - else fix this with the 
    # right field names
    sql = "SELECT id, title, timen category, url FROM VIDEO"
    ls = dbUtil.get_data_tuple_ls(sql)
    video_ls = [Video(*row) for row in ls]
    return video_ls
```

Comment: Thank you @bruno, this is really helpful for me.